# How to expand main container div width as 100% when left and right pane div gets collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a dummy html, in my example when I am clicking on collapse left, left pane div gets collapse and main container div grows automatically but in between right pane div gets misplaced. I wants all div should display in same place during the operation.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#spnColLeft").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".left").is(':visible')) {
      $(".left").animate({
        width: 'hide'
      });
      $(".mainbody").width($(".left").width() + $(".mainbody").width());
      $(this).html("Expand left");
    } else {
      $(".mainbody").width($(".mainbody").width() - $(".left").width());
      $(".left").animate({
        width: 'show'
      });
      $(this).html("Collapse left");

    }
  });

  $("#spnColRight").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".right").is(':visible')) {
      $(".right").animate({
        width: 'hide'
      });
      $(".mainbody").width($(".right").width() + $(".mainbody").width());
      $(this).html("Expand right");
    } else {
      $(".mainbody").width($(".mainbody").width() - $(".right").width());
      $(".right").animate({
        width: 'show'
      });

      $(this).html("Collapse Right");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
[id^=maincontent] {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div > div {
  height: 100px;
  /*demo*/
  float: left;
}
.mainbody {
  width: 79%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.left,
.right {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="spnColLeft">colapse Left</button>
  <button id="spnColRight">colapse Right</button>
</div>
<div id="maincontent1">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="mainbody"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this thing, but this one is suitable. Please have a quick look

```js
$(function() {
  $("#spnColLeft").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".left").is(':visible')) {
      $(".left").animate({
        width: 'hide'
      });
      $(".mainbody").width($(".left").width() + $(".mainbody").width());
      $(this).html("Expand left");
    } else {
      $(".mainbody").width($(".mainbody").width() - $(".left").width());
      $(".left").animate({
        width: 'show'
      });
      $(this).html("Collapse left");

    }
  });

  $("#spnColRight").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".right").is(':visible')) {
      $(".right").animate({
        width: 'hide'
      });
      $(".mainbody").width($(".right").width() + $(".mainbody").width());
      $(this).html("Expand right");
    } else {
      $(".mainbody").width($(".mainbody").width() - $(".right").width());
      $(".right").animate({
        width: 'show'
      });

      $(this).html("Collapse Right");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: yellow;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
}

.left { float: left; }

.right { float: right; }


.center {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="spnColLeft">colapse Left</button>
  <button id="spnColRight">colapse Right</button>
</div>
<div class="main">

  <div class="left"></div>

  <div class="right"></div>

  <div class="center"></div>

</div>
```